Google Pay on testing environment when release to production
I am using react native with the library 'react-native-square-in-app-payments' to use Square for my payments. And i tested it and on testing environment goes perfect. But when i wanted to try on a production environment, when i open the google pay, it says: "Your payment method wont be charged because you're in a test environment". When i am not in a test environment.
This is the first part where I initialize the wallet.
 async componentDidMount() {
try {
  await SQIPCore.setSquareApplicationId(
    'SQUARE_ID',
  );
  await SQIPGooglePay.initializeGooglePay(
    'LOCATION_ID',
    SQIPGooglePay.EnvironmentProduction,
  );
  const googlePaySupported = await SQIPGooglePay.canUseGooglePay();
  if (googlePaySupported) {
    this.setState({canUseWallet: googlePaySupported});
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  Toast.show(
    `Error checking ${
      Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'Apple Pay' : 'Google Pay'
    } availability`,
    Toast.LONG,
  );
  this.setState({canUseWallet: false});
}

}
And in here is when i open the google pay:
   const googlePayConfig = {
    price: totalValue,
    currencyCode,
    priceStatus: SQIPGooglePay.TotalPriceStatusFinal,
  };
  try {
    const result = await SQIPGooglePay.requestGooglePayNonce(
      googlePayConfig,
      this.onGooglePayNonceRequestSuccess,
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('There was an error with the transaction', error);
    Toast.show(error.message, Toast.LONG);
  }

I really dont know what is happening.

Did you reach out to the Square support about this already? If the Google Pay sheet shows the "Your payment method wont be charged because you're in a test environment" message it got invoked in TEST env.
